# How to navigate Python library API documentation

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm wondering how to correctly follow Python library API documentation.

Let's say I want to use `matplotlib.axes.Axes.imshow`.  I go here:

https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.imshow.html

and see that `imshow` returns an `AxesImage` object.  So I go here:

https://matplotlib.org/api/image_api.html#matplotlib.image.AxesImage

and look at all of the methods of an `AxesImage` object. Nowhere on this page are `get_array` and `get_alpha` documented, yet they are methods on the object. For this example, is the documentation incomplete? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you can't find a method listed in a class's documentation, it's most likely that that method is inherited from some parent class, which is the case here.

Unfortunately this can be pretty confusing if you're not familiar with the pattern of building classes on classes on classes while looking through documentation.

Looking at the documentation for `AxesImage`, we can see that `AxesImage` is a subclass of an `_ImageBase` class, which is a subclass of `matplotlib.artist.Artist` and `matplotlib.cm.ScalarMappable`.

Some more digging through the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/cm_api.html#matplotlib.cm.ScalarMappable.get_array) shows me that `matplotlib.cm.ScalarMappable` is the source of the `get_array` and `get_alpha` methods.

https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/cm_api.html#matplotlib.cm.ScalarMappable.get_alpha
https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/cm_api.html#matplotlib.cm.ScalarMappable.get_array

Comment: Thanks. Where did you find that `_ImageBase` is a subclass of `Artist`? I see that `AxesImage` is a subclass of `_ImageBase`, but not that `_ImageBase` is a subclass of `Artist`.

Comment: I found `class _ImageBase(martist.Artist, cm.ScalarMappable):` in the source code here. (do a ctrl-f / cmd-f)
https://matplotlib.org/_modules/matplotlib/image.html#AxesImage

Comment: I see. The documentation is incomplete.